# Unity3d Colliders not working on my characters

Tags: unity, maya, meshcollider

I have create 2 characters in maya and imported them in Unity3d. I am able to move and animate them in unity but the characters are not colliding with each others. I have tried all major colliders capsule, box and mesh. I am kind of stuck in it !

Comment: What exactly are you doing that's causing the problem? How have you tried debugging it? (You can edit to add detail.)

Comment: It is an action game so punches, kicks are performed by the character. But problem is that one character is passing through the other character, No natural physical colliding is occuring. I noticed that in mesh collider MAterial and mesh are none. I have nothing to fill anything in them !

Answer (score 1):

The problem while importing from maya was that the character is too big like 3x times the size of transformer robots. The collider was too small so collision was not detected correctly. 
Most important thing was to apply collider to the bones instead of just using on the mesh. That was the solution.